# How to place underline under a paragraph in itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp in my current project. I have created a table with some underlined data but my requirement is shown in this image:

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/402ap3acf/

How can I build this type of table.

I need the below structure.

```
    A/C Some text           TAT  Some text 
        -----------------        -----------------
```

The doted lines are underline.

Comment: Please help

or share some idea how can I do this

Answer (score 3):

The underline is controlled via the [`Font`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Font.html) object and if you only want to set part of a [`Paragraph`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html) to be underlined you'll want to use a [`Chunk`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html).

Here's a quick helper method for generating a font with different styles. You can change the actual font to whatever font you want to use.

```
Private Shared Function CreateFont(size As Integer, Optional style As Integer = iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL) As iTextSharp.text.Font
    Return New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, size, style)
End Function
```

The `style` parameter takes integers from this list that you `OR` together:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL
iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD
iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC
iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE
iTextSharp.text.Font.STRIKETHRU
```

So normal underlined text would be:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL Or iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE
```

You can use the above like this:

```
Dim P As New Paragraph()
P.Add(New Chunk("A/C ", CreateFont(12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
P.Add(New Chunk("Some text", CreateFont(12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL Or iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE)))
```

**EDIT**

From iTextSharp's perspective, "underline" means "a line drawn underneath text". If there's no text there won't be an underline. A space, however, counts as text so you can just add extra spaces if you want like to continue the underline:

```
Dim P As New Paragraph()
P.Add(New Chunk("A/C ", CreateFont(12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
P.Add(New Chunk("Some text    ", CreateFont(12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL Or iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried this one. But with this the under line will be ended when our words ends.

Need a under line till some width

Comment: This code, **used exactly** produces the phrase "A/C Some text" with the "Some text" part underlined. Does it not do this for you. Is this not what you want?

Comment: See the Underline is not ended when the text ends. It should be certain width.Sorry If I fails to explain properly.

Comment: For better under stand I have changed the image. please have a look.
http://postimg.org/image/402ap3acf/

Comment: Thanks, but how can I know the no of spaces I should append in a test. The "some text" value is coming from database(not static).

Comment: I have no idea. How far past the text do you want the line to extend? Is the line supposed to be twice as long as whatever text is entered?

Comment: No not like that. But thanks for your help. I have fixed this issue. I used a table with 8 columns. Then I am using the Cell.BorderWithBottom=1 for under line. This may not be a good Idea but it fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Thanks your solution is correct as the question I asked. May be I failed to explain you. Thanks a ton. Actually your idea helps me to solve this problem. Thanks a ton, 

Sorry I can't accept your solution :( , as it is partially correct. So please update it.

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914131/how-to-place-underline-on-space-string-in-itextsharp