# How to place underline on space string in ITextSharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

How to add under line under a spacebar. It is not adding space under the empty spaces.

I tried with 2-3 example and it failed to add underline under space.

1.

```
        para = New Paragraph(New Chunk("abc.                ", underlined_font))
        cell = New PdfPCell(para)
        cell.Border = 0
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = 0
        document.Add(cell)
```

2. ```
   Dim str_required_space As New String(" "c, 20)
    para = New Paragraph(New Chunk(str_required_space, underlined_font))
    cell = New PdfPCell(para)
    cell.Border = 0
    cell.BorderWidthBottom = 0
    document.Add(cell)
   ```

I can't use border of cell as the length of the input string is uncertain. So I am using underline.

Please help to add spaces under space.

My Requirement image

[image]

Thanks

[Edit]

If I follow answer 1 then result would be like below

```
asdasd asdsad scasdnk kjashdk kasbas ckasbd ascuasc ksajcasc 
asdansjdnasjakjsnasndasdmlaskdm  
________________________________________________________________
```

But I need Below result.

```
asdasd asdsad scasdnk kjashdk kasbas ckasbd ascuasc ksajcasc 
________________________________________________________________
asdansjdnasjakjsnasndasdmlaskdm  
________________________________________________________________
```

I tried with Ansii Code. Not working for me :(

```
        Dim str_required_space As New String(ChrW(32), (119 - (str_synopsis.Length Mod 119)))

        para = New Paragraph(str_required_space)
        cell = New PdfPCell(para)
        cell.Border = 0
        doc.Add(cell)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read [chapter 2 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf), more specifically the section about vertical position marks, separators, and tabs (section 2.2.6).

Looking at your image (ignoring the soft porn images on that site, please avoid such links in the future), I think you need a line as shown in figure 2.9 (the line under the names of the directors). The code that results in the PDF shown in that screen shot can be found [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=43).

This is how it's done in Java:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("abc.");
LineSeparator line = new LineSeparator(1, 100, null, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, -2);
p.add(line);
document.add(p);
```

It should be a no-brainer to adapt this code to C#. If you do experience problems, then you can find the ported versions of the book samples [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C02).

**What did you do wrong in your code?**

This doesn't make sense:

```
para = New Paragraph(New Chunk("abc.                ", underlined_font))
```

The content of the `Chunk` is trimmed, which explains why the spaces disappear. An alternative would be to use non-breaking space characters (ASCII code 160) instead of regular space characters (ASCII code 32).

**Update**

My previous answer was based on your image and it was the correct answer to your initial question. However: you have now changed your question (instead of creating a new question).

You can meet your requirement by using a page event, more specifically, by implementing the `OnGenericTag()` method. This method is described in [chapter 5 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=5).

In Java, the implementation would look like this:

```
public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document pdfDocument,
    Rectangle rect, String text) {
    Rectangle page = pdfDocument.getPageSize();
    float x1 = page.getRight(pdfDocument.rightMargin());
    float x2 = page.getLeft(pdfDocument.leftMargin());
    float y = rect.getBottom() - 3;
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    canvas.moveTo(x1, y);
    canvas.lineTo(x2, y);
    canvas.stroke();
}
```

You need to create an instance of the page event with that implementation (e.g. a class that you wrote and that you named `MyPageEvent`) and declare that page event to the `PdfWriter` using the `setPageEvent()` method:

```
writer.setPageEvent(new MyPageEvent());
```

You can now declare you `Chunk` and `Paragraph` like this:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(long_text);
chunk.setGenericTag("");
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(chunk);
document.add(p);
```

It is important that you construct your paragraph with only one `Chunk` object. If you have more than one `Chunk` in the paragraph, parts of the line will look thicker.

Comment: Sorry, Actually I search free photo upload site and it suggest me above link. Sorry for that I never checked after upload. I will not use such site next time.

Comment: thanks for the solution, But If I use the above code then it will not work for all the cases. if the paragraph contain more word then it will add an line after the paragraph means 

It will show like
line 1 text
then line 2 text 
then the a line space.

Comment: Please check the question 

I have updated the question.